# How does URLLoader deal with cookies?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, urlloader

I'm using AS3 in Adobe AIR for desktop, not in a browser, I'm not sure if that makes a difference in this situation.

- I'm sending requests to an API using **[`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#)**.
- Each request that I send is coming from a new `URLLoader` instance.

I thought that I would have to deal with the cookies myself, but I'm using **[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)** to trace the HTTP requests and it seems that the cookies are being dealt with automatically even though I'm using a different instance for each request.

My questions:

- Am I right, Is it dealing with these cookies automatically?
- Is there any property to manage this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, just after posting this question I thought that it may be handled by `URLRequest` and not `URLLoader`. It is: [**`URLRequest.manageCookies`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#manageCookies)

So, to answer my own questions:

- Yes it is managing them automatically.
- Yes, it can be managed via the appropriately named `manageCookies` property.